# PHP: Every X weeks for Calendar, Recurring Events

Tags: php, calendar, php-5.3

I'm trying to get every X days from a given date for a calendar.  I think I have the logic down to an extent, but for a small window of dates I am getting unexpected results.

My code below taken from my project:

```
$start_time = 1345935600; //Sept 25th 2011; 
$end_time = 1355011200; //Dec 9th 2011;

$sStartDate = date("Y-m-d", $start_time) . " " . date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:00:00"));
$sEndDate = date("Y-m-d", $end_time) . " " . date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:00:00"));
$sCurrentDate = $sStartDate; 

while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate)
{                                       
    $t_date = strtotime($sCurrentDate);
    $s_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("08/30/2011")));

    $recurs_every = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2; //occurs every 2 days

    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t_date) . " " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $s_date) . " " . (($t_date - $s_date) % $recurs_every) . " " . $recurs_every . "<BR>" ;   

    $sCurrentDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));                                               
}
```

Outputs (current date - start date - modular) :

```
2011-09-25 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 0
2011-09-26 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 86400
....
2012-10-27 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 0
2012-10-28 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 86400
2012-10-29 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 3600
2012-10-30 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 90000
2012-10-31 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 3600
2012-11-01 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 90000
2012-11-02 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 3600
2012-11-03 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 90000
2012-11-04 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 3600
2012-11-05 00:00:00 2011-08-30 00:00:00 90000
```

The last few lines are the issue for me.

3600 is one hour and I don't know where this is coming from.  Strange thing is, fast forward to march 26 2012 and it starts to work again but same error occurs at Oct 29 2012...

I've been at this for a few hours and can't figure this out.  Any help really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some contries there is a summer & winter time where the clock is converted one hour (@ 27 march & 30 oct). Therefore there is a one hour difference.

-> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Example:

```
<?

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$start_time = 1345935600; //Sept 25th 2011; 
$end_time = 1355011200; //Dec 9th 2011;

$sStartDate = date("Y-m-d", $start_time) . " " . date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:00:00"));
$sEndDate = date("Y-m-d", $end_time) . " " . date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:00:00"));
$sCurrentDate = $sStartDate; 

$lastDate = 0;
$corr = 0;

while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate)
{                                       
    $t_date = strtotime($sCurrentDate);
    $s_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("08/30/2011")));

    $recurs_every = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2; //occurs every 2 days

    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t_date) . " " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $s_date) . " " . (($t_date - $s_date + $corr) % $recurs_every) . " " . $recurs_every . "<BR>" ;   

    $lastDate = strtotime($sCurrentDate);
    $sCurrentDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));             

    if(strtotime($sCurrentDate) - $lastDate != 60 * 60 * 24) {
        $corr -= strtotime($sCurrentDate) - $lastDate - 60 * 60 * 24;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with that.  My brain is mush at the moment.  Could you perhaps update my code to solve it?

Comment: I edited my post. Should be something like this. Probably not the best solution but should work (in my tests it did).

Answer (score 0):

I have given you the answer for answering the question and the effort.  In the end, I had a rethink and did more googling and this is what I have come up with.

```
$start_time = 1316905200;
$end_time = 1320537600;

$sStartDate = date("Y-m-d", $start_time);
$sEndDate = date("Y-m-d", $end_time);

$sStartDate = new DateTime($sStartDate);
$sEndDate = new DateTime($sEndDate);

$sCurrentDate = $sStartDate; 
$recurs_every = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2; //occurs every 2 days

while($sCurrentDate->format('U') < $sEndDate->format('U'))
{       
    $s_date = new DateTime("08/30/2011");

    echo $sCurrentDate->format('Y-m-d') . " " . $s_date->format('Y-m-d') . " " . ceil(($sCurrentDate->format('U') - $s_date->format('U') - (chkTransitions($sCurrentDate->format('U')) == 'GMT' ? 3600 : 0)) % $recurs_every) . "<BR>";

    $sCurrentDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));    
}

function chkTransitions($dt)
{
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
    $transitions = $timezone->getTransitions($dt, $dt);

    $offset = $transitions[0]['offset']; 
    $abbr = $transitions[0]['abbr']; 

    return $abbr;
}
```